# Stripe: Accessing a payout from a charge

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am trying to access a `payout` object (https://stripe.com/docs/api#payouts) from a `charge` object (https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges). The problem is that I do not know what ID to use for the `payout`. I tried using the `transfer` ID from `payouts` but I get the error:

`No such payout: tr_1Bxxxxxxxxxx`

I also know that the ID of the `payout` is in the format `po_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` but I can't find any from the `charge`, the `transfer` and the `balanced_transaction`. How is the `payout` related to the charge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a direct way to get the `Payout` from a `Charge` object `ch_xxxyyyzzz`, but if your account is setup to make automatic payouts, you can get a list of charges and any other balance transactions (refunds, adjustments, etc) that make up a specific payout object.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#balance_history-payout

```
stripe.balance.listTransactions({payout:"po_xxxyyyyyyzzz",limit: 100 }, 
function(err, transactions) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

Payouts and Transfers are two separate types of Objects. A Payout always refers to when moving funds from your balance to your bank account. A Transfer refers to funds moving between Stripe accounts, typically in the context of Stripe's Connect.

https://stripe.com/docs/transfer-payout-split

Comment: Oh perfect, balance has what I need! Thank you!